# One Job in SQL agent run twice in same time (like a parallel)

Tags: sql, sql-agent-job, sql-job, clrstoredprocedure

we have jobs in sql agent runnig schedually. We know at least about one job (scheduled every day at three different times - morning, afternoon, night) which rarely (apx one per several months) fires/runs twice in same time (like a parallel). But it is scheduled only one time in same moment. Job runs CLR stored procedure which launch console application which process some getting data and recalculating

This behaviour causes problems for us.

Why?
How could it happend?
Where is problem?
But where is reason?

Thank you for all ideas.

(Of course, we should handle it and prevent this behaviour.)

I found error in job history according to time of job execution - error 6535.
This error appears twice for this job iteration. Firstly without addtional message, secondly with additional message "The step suceeded". When I looking for information about his error 6535 - i found that this error occurs on sql server 2005, but due to select @@version, the customer use sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Hi there. In your SQL Server Agent job step, do you have the "_Include step output in history_" option selected? If not, please do that. It's on the "Advanced" tab. You might also need to specify an "_Output file_" and check the "_Append output to existing file_" option. Please update the question to include the _full_ and _exact_ error message. An error number by itself is rarely helpful. Also, do both of the paralell executions show up in the job history? Could one of the executions be coming from another job (not another schedule) or manual execution or a Windows Scheduled Task?

Comment: Hi, now, i have set "Include step output in history" to this job step. Thew full messages belong to this problem:

Comment: 1.runnig at 02:10:00 throw this message: .NET Framework execution was aborted. Another query caused the Domain XY.CLRLogin[runtime].5 to be unloaded.   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.  System.Threading.ThreadAbortException:      at MSSQL_Utils.StoredProcedures.SP_CLR_XY() [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 6535),00:00:41,16,6535,,,,0

Comment: 2.Runnig at 02:11:41 throw this message: .NET Framework execution was aborted. Another query caused the Domain XY.CLRLogin[runtime].5 to be unloaded.   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.  System.Threading.ThreadAbortException:      at MSSQL_Utils.StoredProcedures.SP_CLR_XYt() [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 6535).  The step succeeded.,00:04:46,16,6535,,,,0

Comment: The Job is scheduled at 02:10:00. So second running is unsolicited. OK, first running returned expextion, so sql agnt tries second running? But finally why both of this runnig were processed

Comment: No no, no other job could start this stored procedure

Comment: We have set on this job Retry attemps on 1 and Retry interval on 1 minute - this could be the reason, why it was runig after one minute ones more.